# Use cache memory to store video while playing in ionic 2

Tags: caching, angular, typescript, ionic2

> Hi all,

I am new in Ionic 2, I am working on an application which having list of videos.

**1. Requirement:-**
  When I play a video from the list, it get downloaded while playing, 
  when I play same video next time, it checks if this video has been played already, so does not need to play from URL, it play from local without streaming and buffering.

I want to use cache to store video which I played so that i can use that to play locally-
As we can do in ionic like this 
https://libraries.io/bower/ionic-cache-src

- set of work to do-

**Must be used IONIC 2**

I need to play some videos from given URL, and download along with playing.

*store video locally.*

if same video get play again then get buffer from local not from internet.

The same can be see [there as](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-download-video-while-playing-in-ionic-2/57927)-

Need help....

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Comment: No @Sampath,  I am doing that using another way.

Comment: Can you please share the way you are working on? Me too have a same kind of requirement.Thanks.

Comment: Sure but that is only temporary, you can vote up and "Star" this question, as soon any answer get posted, you will get notify.

Comment: Found any solution for this? I have same requirement